# scala case class equals (==) not working as expected

Tags: scala, equality, case-class

I must be missing something silly here. I have this:

```
case class Color(val rgb:Int) {
   private val c = rgb - 0xff000000
   val r = (c & 0xff0000) >> 16
   val g = (c & 0x00ff00) >> 8
   val b = (c & 0x0000ff)
}

case object Red extends Color(0xffff0000)
case object Green extends Color(0xff00ff00)
case object Blue extends Color(0xff0000ff)
```

Then I expect this to print **true**:

```
val c = Color(0xff00ff00)
println(c == Green)
```

Why doesn't it??

Comment: Another tip: the `val` in the argument to `Color` is redundant, since `Color` is a case class. It's sufficient to say: `case class Color(rgb: Int)`

Comment: Yes, that was a late addition as I was trying to make it work as I expected; now that you mention it, I remember it isn't needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Case classes (or objects) inheriting from case classes is a bad practice, and is illegal as of Scala 2.9.1. Use `object` instead of `case object` to define `Red`, `Green` and `Blue`.

Comment: case object create `equals`, `hashcode` and `apply/unapply`. Why is it bad practice?

Comment: @Amir Raminfar: No, it actually doesn't in this case, because the methods already exist on `Color` and `case` only creates these methods if they aren't already overridden. @4e6: it doesn't matter if you use `object` or `case object` if you are still inheriting from a case class!

Comment: Ah you mean subclassing a case class. I think you should change the wording because it sounds like you are saying using `case objects` is bad in general.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov , the issue is case-to-case inheritence. It's ok if a non case object inherits from a case class. I updated the answer to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks, @kipton. That's what I meant.

Comment: At any rate, I'd define `Red`, `Green` and `Blue` as `val`s in `object Color`.

Comment: Maybe somebody else wrote the class color, and you want to define some not so popular color like petrol or elephant.

Comment: Is it better to have a case class at the root of the inheritance or at the leaf? (assuming that I only have one case class and all others normal classes).

Answer (score 0):

Why *should* that be true?  Green is a companion object, c is an instance.  They *aren't* equal.

Comment: It's a bug with case-to-case inheritance, which is now illegal. The code works when the case modifier is removed from the objects, because the definition of `==` on case classes checks equality of the arguments (here, `rgb`). By the way, `Green` is not a companion object to class `Color`. A companion object needs to have the same name as the trait/class, and (I think) needs to be defined in the same file. More info on why companion objects are useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609744/what-is-the-rationale-behind-having-companion-objects-in-scala

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a relevant question: "Why case object and case class it extends are not equal".

Using Scala 2.12.2

I added following lines to your example and and now object is equal to the class instance.

```
object Black extends Color(0x00000000)
val black1 = Color(0x00000000)
black1 == Black
```

*res1: Boolean = true*