# "new" keyword in Scala

Tags: scala, new-operator, keyword

I have a very simple question - when should we apply the new keyword when creating objects in Scala? Is it when we try to instantiate Java objects only?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Use the `new` keyword when you want to refer to a `class`'s own constructor:

```
class Foo { }

val f = new Foo
```

Omit `new` if you are referring to the companion object's `apply` method:

```
class Foo { }
object Foo {
    def apply() = new Foo
}

// Both of these are legal
val f = Foo()
val f2 = new Foo
```

If you've made a case class:

```
case class Foo()
```

Scala secretly creates a companion object for you, turning it into this:

```
class Foo { }
object Foo {
    def apply() = new Foo
}
```

So you can do

```
f = Foo()
```

Lastly, keep in mind that there's no rule that says that the companion `apply`
method has to be a proxy for the constructor:

```
class Foo { }
object Foo {
    def apply() = 7
}

// These do different things
> println(new Foo)
test@5c79cc94
> println(Foo())
7
```

And, since you mentioned Java classes: yes -- Java classes rarely have
companion objects with an `apply` method, so you must use `new` and the actual
class's constructor.

Comment: A Java class can never have a companion object. It can have an object which can work as a Factory for the Java class - but this object is not its companion object.

Comment: @Antoras Since Scala classes compile to Java bytecode, and can be distributed in compiled form, can Scala tell the difference between an actual Scala companion and a class named Foo$ with a static MODULE$ member?

Comment: I think scalac can differ this because it is spec'ed that a companion object has to be declared in the same file as its companion class. Because the companion "property" exists only in Scala and not on Bytecode-level scalac has to check the Scala code and not the Bytecode to be sure that the spec is followed.

Comment: Any examples of Java classes that DO NOT use new keyword in Scala?

Comment: Also the methods on the companion object will be made accessible through static methods on the class as well and that will never happen with java classes for which you define a "companion" later on.

Comment: very comprehensive description of the whole topic! this should be part of any scala course :-)

Answer (score 16):

> Is it when we try to instantiate java objects only?

Not at all. There is two general cases when you ommit `new` in scala.
With singleton objects (that are oftenly used to store static functions and as a kind of factory similar to what you may seen in java):

```
scala> object LonelyGuy { def mood = "sad" }
defined module LonelyGuy

scala> LonelyGuy
res0: LonelyGuy.type = LonelyGuy$@3449a8

scala> LonelyGuy.mood
res4: java.lang.String = sad
```

With a [case classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312881/what-is-the-difference-between-scalas-case-class-and-class) (actually, underneath there are class + object = [companion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609744/what-is-the-rationale-behind-having-companion-objects-in-scala) pattern, e.g. having class and object with the same name):

```
scala> case class Foo(bar: String) 
defined class Foo


scala> Foo("baz")
res2: Foo = Foo(baz)
```

So when you work with a simple classes, rules are the same as with Java.

```
scala> class Foo(val bar: String) 
defined class Foo

scala> new Foo("baz")
res0: Foo = Foo@2ad6a0

// will be a error 
scala> Foo("baz")
<console>:8: error: not found: value Foo
       Foo("baz")
```

Bonus, there is a anonymous classes in scala, which can be constructed like this:

```
scala> new { val bar = "baz" }
res2: java.lang.Object{val bar: java.lang.String} = $anon$1@10ee5b8

scala> res2.bar
res3: java.lang.String = baz
```

Comment: You okay there bud?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it when we try to instantiate Java objects only?

With Scala 3 (which should be released mid 2020, eight years later), [based on Dotty](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty): never.

Scala 3 will drop "`new`", as [in this thread](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/expunging-new-from-scala-3/2868/104)

> Creator applications allow to use simple function call syntax to create instances
>   of a class, even if there is no apply method implemented.
>
> Example:

```
class StringBuilder(s: String) {
   def this() = this(s)
}

StringBuilder("abc")  // same as new StringBuilder("abc")
StringBuilder()       // same as new StringBuilder()
```

> Creator applications generalize a functionality provided so far only for case classes, but the mechanism how this is achieved is slightly different.
>   Instead of an auto-generated apply method, we add a new possible interpretation to a function call `f(args)`.