# When is new required in scala

Tags: scala, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“new” keyword in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727637/new-keyword-in-scala)

Ive noticed that creating certain instances in Scala you can leave off using `new`. When is it required that a developer use `new`? And why do some objects allow you to miss off using it?

Thanks

> List("this","is","a","list") creates a List of those four strings; no
>   new required
>
> Map("foo" -> 45, "bar" ->76) creates a Map of String to Int, no new
>   required and no clumsy helper class.

Taken from [here](http://www.naildrivin5.com/scalatour/wiki_pages/ScalaBasics)..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general the scala collection classes define factory methods in their companion object using the `apply` method. The `List("this","is","a","list")` and `Map("foo" -> 45, "bar" ->76)` are syntactic sugar for calling those apply methods. Using this convention is fairly idiomatic scala.

In addition if you define a `case class C(i: Int)` it also defines a factory `C.apply(i: Int)` method which can be called as `C(i)`. So no *new* needed.

Other than that, the `new` is required to create objects.