# Scala: companion object purpose

Tags: class, scala, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the rationale behind having companion objects in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609744/what-is-the-rationale-behind-having-companion-objects-in-scala)

Thanks for all responses to my previous post( [Scala: companion objects and "new" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794640/scala-companion-objects-and-new-keyword)). I would like to ask you what is the general purpose of a companion object in Scala?
Firstly, could we not have included all the methods, such as apply, in the forms of contructor/method definition on the class itself?
Furthermore, what is the point of a companion Boolean object, as it does not even define apply method?

Thanks again in advance for all your responses.

Comment: The [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9806136/39396) is better than the accepted answer to the duplicate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Companion objects are needed to:

- declare methods related to the companion's class which would otherwise be static (unlike in Java, you cannot declare a static method within the class itself in Scala)
- declare the `unapply` and `unapplySeq` methods to define custom extractors for pattern matching (see [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112))
- declare the `apply` method which is typically used as a factory method that creates objects of the particular class (but doesn't have to be)
- companion objects can access private fields and methods of their companion trait/class - useful for creating static operations on that particular trait/class
- they are important for the [implicit resolution](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/114) -- when looking for an implicit value of a certain type, the companion object of that type is inspected to see if there exists a corresponding `implicit` definition; see the exact rules of implicit resolution in the [Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) or a short summary in [this blog post](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/04/implicit-parameter-resolution.html)

The `Boolean` object in the Scala standard library provides the methods `box` and `unbox` used to convert between primitive booleans and their wrapped, object representations. It is additionally (currently) used as an argument to the `@specialized` annotation, to denote on which primitive types the class needs to be specialized on.

Comment: So in the case of a boolean,box/unbox play a role of a static-like method for Java? in Java we would have Boolean.Box(boolean b) definition?

Comment: If you used Scala standard library from within a Java program, you would see the `box` method as a static method.