# Add WrappedRequest to Play! Template as implicit (Implicit resolution failing?)

Tags: scala, playframework

I've created a WrappedRequest

```
 class AuthenticatedRequest[A](login: LoginEntity, theme: Option[ThemeEntity], request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)
```

I'd like to pass the request implicitly

```
 def show = Auth { implicit request: AuthenticatedRequest => 
   Ok(html.show("Greetings"))
 }
```

to my template show.scala.html

```
@import controllers.actions.Authenticated.AuthenticatedRequest

@(greeting: String)(implicit request: AuthenticatedRequest[_])
```

But importing fails --

```
object Authenticated is not a member of package controllers.actions
[error] Note: trait Authenticated exists, but it has no companion object.
```

Authenticated trait is a trait that the Controller integrates

```
trait Authenticated { this: Controller => ...
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Looks like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806029/scala-companion-object-purpose) is relevant:

> [companion objects] are important for the implicit resolution -- when
>   looking for an implicit value of a certain type, the companion object
>   of that type is inspected to see if there exists a corresponding
>   implicit definition; see the exact rules of implicit resolution in the
>   Scala specification or a short summary in this blog post

Comment: Where is defined `AuthenticatedRequest`, inside the trait? If yes, the template cannot use it for me

Comment: thanks -- yeah the AuthenticatedRequest is defined inside of the Authenticated trait.