# Initializing Scala regex in PySpark for Scala class constructor

Tags: java, python, regex, scala, pyspark

I am working in a Jupyter Notebook with PySpark v2.3.4 which runs on Java 8, Python 3.6 (with py4j==0.10.7), and Scala 2.11, and I have a Scala case class that takes in a `scala.util.matching.Regex` ([scala doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex)) as an arg like so:

```
case class myClass(myString: String, myRegex: Regex)
```

I would like to construct an object from `myClass` but I can't seem to figure out how to construct a `scala.util.matching.Regex` object in a Python / PySpark environment. Below are a couple of my attempts/docs I've followed to create a Scala regex where `sc` is my SparkContext.

- `sc._jvm.scala.util.matching.Regex("""(S|s)cala""")`

  - Error: `Constructor scala.util.matching.Regex([class java.lang.String]) does not exist`
  - This error message dumbfounds me because the Scala 2.11 docs clearly state that its constructor takes in a `java.lang.String`.
- `sc._jvm.scala.util.matching.Regex("(S|s)cala")`

  - Same error as above
- `sc._jvm.scala.util.matching.Regex(r"(S|s)cala")`

  - Same error as above
- `sc._jvm.scala.util.matching.Regex("(S|s)cala".r)` (the way they do it in Scala)

  - Error: Python string does not have attribute "r"
- `sc._jvm.java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(S|s)cala")` successfully creates a Java regex pattern -- and the scala doc clearly states that the Scala regex delegates to the Java regex package...

Any help/advice would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: So according to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727637/new-keyword-in-scala) it seems that `new Regex` vs `Regex()` should be the roughly the same where the former uses the Regex class's own constructor while the latter refers to a companion object's `apply` method. I might need to overload the singleton Scala function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out lol

Scala Regex takes a second argument called `groupNames`. It is a variable String argument  that should accept args of length 0 to as many String arguments as you want. However, from a Python interpreter, this is seen as a required argument, so you must pass a `None` into this argument to indicate nothing to populate this second arg.

```
sc._jvm.scala.util.matching.Regex("(S|s)cala", None)
```

NOTE: I haven't figured out how to pass in a vararg yet though... Passing comma separated strings, array, and tuples didn't work... Any help on that would be great thanks :)