# What is the added value of a companion object over a normal object?

Tags: scala

I'd like to know what is the advantage of a companion object to a class over having an object define in the same file or not and being accessed from that class.

So far i don't see the real advantage of the companion object.

I understand Object very well and their versality, i don't understand the specific of companion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609744/what-is-the-rationale-behind-having-companion-objects-in-scala

Comment: It's mostly about scope and access modifiers.