# Why in scala we need to define class structure to create new object of the same class

Tags: scala

```
class ReadHelper{}
object ReadHelper {}

class MainApp{
   val rHelp = ReadHelper//This line will be uneasy if I omit class declaration of ReadHelper
}
```

Comment: What's the error you get then? It works just fine for me.

Comment: Because this is the purpose of writing classes. If you have a Java-background, you could imagine the object definition as the place for all static methods in the class, the class definition the place for the other stuff. You could delete both, if you don't need one of them.

Comment: I am getting error as "not found: type ReadHelper"

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar are you sure? This error occures when i remove `object Readhelper {}`, not the class?

Answer (score 4):

> Why in scala we need to define class structure to create new object of
>   the same class?

Actually we don't.

```
class ReadHelper{}

class MainApp{
  val rHelp: ReadHelper = new ReadHelper
}
```

Please pay attention that in the original case

```
class ReadHelper {}
object ReadHelper {}

class MainApp{
  val rHelp: ReadHelper.type = ReadHelper
}
```

or just

```
object ReadHelper {}

class MainApp{
  val rHelp: ReadHelper.type = ReadHelper
}
```

`rHelp` has a different type.

`object ReadHelper` is not an object (aka *instance* in OOP-languages) of `class ReadHelper`. It's so called [companion object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609744/what-is-the-rationale-behind-having-companion-objects-in-scala) of the class. This is a class-like structure (a singleton) existing besides the class. In byte code you will find two classes `ReadHelper` (the class itself) and `ReadHelper$` (companion object).

Maybe you should [read more](https://docs.scala-lang.org/) about classes, objects, companion objects in Scala.