# Spanning trait variables over multiple subclasses

Tags: scala, class, traits

I have a trait that is extended by two classes. Is there any way that change made to a trait variable from one class reflect in the second class?

Let's see for a simple code like this

```
trait parent {
    var a: Int = 0;
}

class child1 extends parent {
    def setValue(n: Int) = a = n
}

class child2 extends parent {
    def getValue() : Int = a
}

object parentTest extends App {
    val c = new child1()
    c.setValue(2)
    val d = new child2()
    println(d.getValue)
}
```

I want to have `d` value printed as `2`. If not with traits, is there any other way to access the same variable across multiple classes so that changes made in one also appear to other class?

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Rewriting your own Future-Promise implementation? If not - what are you trying to do, exactly? Communicate over shared mutable state?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Working on a distributed program. I update these values in worker nodes and want to read them in the master node. I can send the values from worker to master but these are just indexing/storage variables and not result of any operations so do not want to pass them from worker to master.

Comment: So, you *are* using shared mutable state for communication in a distributed program. That never ends well, please don't do this. Use something like Akka instead.

Comment: Sure, will check that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `var` in a companion object and put the setter and getter code in the trait.

```
object Parent {private var a :Int = 0}
trait Parent {
  def set(x :Int) :Unit = Parent.a = x
  def get :Int = Parent.a
}

class Child1 extends Parent
class Child2 extends Parent

val c1 = new Child1
val c2 = new Child2
c1.set(9)  //res0: Unit = ()
c2.get     //res1: Int = 9

Parent.a = 6 //Error: variable a in object Parent cannot be accessed in object A$A83.this.Parent
```

If the `var` is private then it can only be accessed in the companion trait.

Comment: No `synchronized` anywhere? That definitely won't end well... ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Java you would use static variables, Scala solves most of these use-cases using [companion objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609744/what-is-the-rationale-behind-having-companion-objects-in-scala).

You could create your trait so it stores the variable using a (companion) object.

A drawback would be that anyone with access to the object could modify its state, but I think a java + static solution probably would have the same drawback. If you want to prevent this I think you'd need some sort of a factory to create the instances of your classes that will provide them a shared variable reference during construction.